# Get Authorization Code From Callback Query

Tags: python, api, https, spotify, spotipy

I'm currently working with the Spotify API. To work with it, I need to get the user to authorise and give permission for me to use their account data. After the user provides this permission, they are redirected to the Spotify homepage. In the URL of the homepage, they are taken to two query parameters including an authorisation code like so: `https://open.spotify.com/?code=AQAKS1CbcTdK3...7JSQ`.
How do I now get this code from the URL? I'm very new to this kind of programming so, if there is something I explained poorly, this is the link to where I got this info: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/

Thanks so much to anyone who can help :)

Comment: I open a URL given to me by the Spotify API. I'm not running any server or anything myself. This URL is the URL the the user uses to give permission to use their Spotify data

Comment: So, it would be impractical to get this code if I set the redirect URI to the Spotify homepage? Is it still possible tho?

Comment: So, either way, I still need to create my own web app?

Comment: I want to just use the Spotify API to get the current song I'm listening to.